# Why is there no $1S_{-1/2} $ state of the hydrogen atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, quantum-spin, atomic-physics, hydrogen

Heyho,

i found this term scheme for the hydrogen atom:

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/94/Wasserstoff_Aufspaltung.svg

I was wondering why there is only a $1S_\frac{1}{2}$ state and not a $1S_{-\frac{1}{2}}$ state? Same goes for the higher n states. Why can the total momentum J not be negative?
By definition $ J = L + S $. So in the $1S_\frac{1}{2}$ state where $L=0$ why can S only be $\frac{1}{2}$ and not $-\frac{1}{2}$ ?

sincerely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When labeling states of the hydrogen atom, one doesn't refer to the z component of the angular momentum, but rather to the total angular momentum.

The total angular momentum is positive, but, as you've stated, there are two states for $J=\frac{1}{2}$ with $L=0$, and those are $J_z=\pm\frac{1}{2}$ (Or some linear combination of them)

As to why this is, first of all, what is negative total angular momentum?
And secondly, these are the rules of addition for the $SU(2)$ group, $0\oplus\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Hm I see, a negativ angular momentum would only make sense if we take the direction into account, then i suppose it would be simply the angular momentum in the opposite direction ?
So if we speak about the angular momentum itself without the direction we only talk about the absolut value?

Comment: Yes, which is why the operators we discuss in QM are $J^2, J_i$